# RecyclerView doesn't show items when BottomNavigationBar is clicked twice

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

I have a recycler view inside a fragment of BottonNavigationView Activity. I have three columns Each have a RecyclerView inside them. When I click a view twice the RecyclerView items disappear.

This is the `BottomNavActivity`. I haven't changed anything in this. This is the BottomNavActivity template in AndroidStudio.

```
public class BottomActivityHome extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bottom_home);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

}
```

This is the `BottonNavActivity`'s layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_bar_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_bar_colors"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Also, this is the fragment's `onViewCreated` method

```
super.onViewCreated(view, savesInstanceState);
        ArrayList<MetricDataModel> amdm = new ArrayList<>();
        amdm.add(new MetricDataModel("<random Id>", "100 gms"));
        amdm.add(new MetricDataModel("<random Id>", "200 gms"));
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            mDataset.add(new CommodityDataModel(
                    "<name>",
                    "<Link for image>",
                    amdm,
                    "gms",
                    22.4
            ));
        }

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcyview_commodities);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new CommoditiesAdapter(mDataset, this.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

When I click twice on the bottom button the Recycler view suddenly stops showing and shows a blank screen.

This is the error it shows when I tap for the second time.

```
E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_DOWN
I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=42KB, data=62KB
I/art: After code cache collection, code=42KB, data=62KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
I/ViewRootImpl: ViewRoot's Touch Event : ACTION_UP
```

It works fine when I go to a different page and come back. But it doesn't work when I click on the same page twice.

Comment: This is kind of confusing... Can you try replacing `recyclerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rcyview_commodities);` by `recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.rcyview_commodities);`?

Comment: @JuanMartinez Okay. Will change that

Comment: I can see you updated the code example. Did you replace it in your code? Is the behavior still the same?

Comment: @JuanMartinez Yes I did and It is the same

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and this occurs

because you didn't hide other Fragments Before showing the one you want to show

Try implementing BottomNavigationView With This Way

### Code Here

https://github.com/bukunmialuko/BottomNavViewWithFragments/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ng/com/obkm/bottomnavviewwithfragments/MainActivity.java

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33116758)